# Dockerfile - How to set ENV variable up by reading content of local file in

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm working on a Ruby application and I set the version to use in a`.ruby-version` file.

```
2.5.0
```

I use Docker to deploy the application and in my `Dockerfile` I set the version to be installed in an environment variable.

```
ENV RUBY_VERSION 2.5.0
```

I'd like to be able to refer to the value in the `.ruby-version` file at the time of build instead of hard-write the version.

So, I need to update the value just in one place instead of multiple ones.

I have looked around but nothing seems to address my issue.

Comment: you can set variable with docker-compose

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't really answer my question. I need the Ruby version in my Dockerfile since the image must have the correct Ruby interpreter installed. Docker-compose does not seem a viable solution to me.

Comment: docker supports  .env file for environment variables if thats what you looking for. here is a [blogpost](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> --build-arg varname=value

while building using docker build. So your dockerfile will contain

> ARG RUBY_ARG

and you can set the environment variable using ARG

> ENV RUBY_ENV=$RUBY_ARG

and the command will be:

> docker build --build-arg RUBY_ARG=version .

You can use bash functionality to read from file and pass it as ARG.

Comment: Not sure that will work with Docker Hub. Thanks anyway.